# Cracking ellbow and shoulder at pushups

Tags: exercise-technique, push-ups, upper-body-workout, bodyweight

While making push-ups my left elbow and left shoulder crack sometimes. Interestingly, when I do the same movement leaning against a wall there is no cracking sound.

What can I do against the cracking? Or can I just go on? I do classical push-ups, maybe there is a better alternative in my case? I have no pain and no medical history in those joints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Crepitus by itself is not cause for concern.

[Barbell Medicine has an article on this](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/crepitus-expectations-vs-reality). In the intro, Dr. Baraki summarizes for us:

> Crepitus is the menacingly-named phenomenon of noises produced by a joint during movement. It is common to hear snaps, crackles, and pops when flexing or extending a knee or an elbow. At times, these noises can be accompanied by a sensation of mechanical stiffness. When combined, these can cause distress, evoking deep-seated fears people have about their bodies “wearing out”. It leads many to seek consultation with a health care provider, even in the absence of pain or functional limitation. The good news is that not only is crepitus very common, it does not necessarily portend dire outcomes, nor should it be something that keeps us from moving, training, and otherwise enjoying an active and fulfilling existence.

Full details and references are contained in the article, but noisy joints in the absence of pain is simply not cause for concern.

Comment: Yep, all it means is that your cartilage isn't smooth as glass anymore which, in turn, is pretty normal at some point past puberty hehe